# Passing multiple objects to my controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am passing an object to my controller like so:

```
var form = JSON.stringify({
        "subRevisedRequest": $('#frmRevised').val(),
        "subSubcontractor": $('#frmSubcontractor').val(),
        "subDescription": $('#frmDesc').val(),
        "subCostCode": $('#frmCostCode').val(),
        "subAmt": $('#frmAmt').val(),
        "subPaymentTerms": "terms",
        "subRetainage": 10,
        "subComments": $('#frmComment').val()
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateSubcontracts", "Routing")',
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: form,
        success: function(result) {
            if (!result.success) {
                $('#errormsg').empty();
                $('#errormsg').append(result.message);
            } else {
                location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
```

my controller sees this as the object it is looking for:

```
public ActionResult CreateSubcontracts(RoutingSubcontracts s)
```

My problem is that I'd like to pass along just one more string.  I know I can make a view specific model but I was wondering if I could do something like this for example:

```
public ActionResult CreateSubcontracts(RoutingSubcontracts s, string bu)
```

I have tried the the following with no luck:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "s": form, "bu": "251" }),
```

but the complex object just comes through as null.  Is there a way I can pass the object and a string through as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the string item in the JSON you already have. Dont stringify it or it will just send a big string that youll have to parse again on the server.

```
var form = {
    "subRevisedRequest": $('#frmRevised').val(),
    "subSubcontractor": $('#frmSubcontractor').val(),
    "subDescription": $('#frmDesc').val(),
    "subCostCode": $('#frmCostCode').val(),
    "subAmt": $('#frmAmt').val(),
    "subPaymentTerms": "terms",
    "subRetainage": 10,
    "subComments": $('#frmComment').val(),
    "bu": "251"    // add it here
};

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CreateSubcontracts", "Routing")',
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "JSON",
    data: form,
    success: function(result) {
        if (!result.success) {
            $('#errormsg').empty();
            $('#errormsg').append(result.message);
        } else {
            location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: for some reason i still need to stringlfy the first json object, otherwise I am just getting 500 errors.  but adding it seems to have fixed it.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your view jquery create a second var for bu. Assign the data in you ajax call like this;

```
data: { "s" : form, "bu" : "251" }
```

In your controller method change the signature to include a default value for bu like this;

```
public ActionResult CreateSubcontracts(RoutingSubcontracts s, string bu = "NoValue")
```

With the default value set bu will act like an optional parameter