# Passing an object and primitives to a Controller via JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Started by looking at a similar thread, but the Solution there didn't work for me.

[Passing multiple objects to my controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148599/passing-multiple-objects-to-my-controller)

Here is my javascript onclick event:

```js
var test = function () {
        var vm = {
            "IsNew": true,
            "SelectedId": 1,
            "SelectedCode": null
        };
        var idk= JSON.stringify(vm);
        $.ajax({
            url: $("base").attr("href") + "Controller/ComplexityTest",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: idk,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('success')
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    };
```

On my Controller, I have this endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ComplexityTest([FromBody] MyViewModel vm, long categoryId, long personId, DateTime startDate)
    {
        //...do work
    }
```

For simplicity, let's say this is my Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool IsNew {get; set;}
    public int SelectedId {get; set;}
    public string SelectedCode {get; set;}
}
```

On running this, I'm able to see that vm is populated correctly. The issue is that I'm also trying to populate some additional primitives to be sent along with MyViewModel.

I've tried adding the additional fields inside my vm initializer, and stringifying the whole thing.

I've tried setting data to { "vm": idk, "categoryId": 1, etc... }.

Everything I've tried so far has caused me to not only get the new parameters, but to lose my original vm object as well.

How do I go about passing an object (class) and multiple primitives to a POST method? Do I just need to create a new DTO object containing the additional parameters, and send that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `url` ajax param , use this

```
url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ComplexityTest", "Home", new { categoryId = 123, personId = 456, startDate = "2019-07-19" }))',
```

I honestly don't know why `Url.Action` doesn't work properly in .net core, but I used `Html.Raw` to make it work. ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

[image]

...but it works....

Comment: Ultimately, I did end up creating a new model that encapsulated all the parameters I needed, simply because I didn't want them showing up in the query string. But your advice set me down the right track. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it in javascript

```
var test = function () {
    var vm = {
        "IsNew": true,
        "SelectedId": 1,
        "SelectedCode": null
    };
    var obj = { vm: vm, categoryId: 1, personId:3, startDate:new Date() };

    var idk= JSON.stringify(obj);
    $.ajax({
        url: $("base").attr("href") + "Controller/ComplexityTest",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: idk,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('success')
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
```

I don't really know what `$("base").attr("href")` is getting for you but I tried just `/Controller/ComplexityTest`

Also I did not use `[FromBody] MyViewModel vm` I used `MyViewModel vm` instead

Comment: I don't know if it's .Net Core related, or if another gremlin is involved, but I wasn't able to get this approach to post any data back to the controller. The best I could do was to stringify only the vm object, then change my endpoint to accept a string and manually convert it to the class I was expecting.